# Error LNK2005: DllGetClassObject Already Defined in dlldata.obj - COM Class Creation Issue

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com, midl

I'm currently exploring the process of creating a COM Class, and I've run into an issue regarding the `DllGetClassObject` function. When attempting to create a COM object, I've encountered an error message that states:

```
1>dlldata.obj : error LNK2005: _DllGetClassObject@12 already defined in BasicComShapesDll.obj
1>   Creating library E:\Projects\Visual Studio\ComSession\BasicComShapesDll\Release\BasicComShapesDll.lib and object E:\Projects\Visual Studio\ComSession\BasicComShapesDll\Release\BasicComShapesDll.exp
1>E:\Projects\Visual Studio\ComSession\BasicComShapesDll\Release\BasicComShapesDll.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "BasicComShapesDll.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Here is a description of the steps I've taken and the code I'm working with:

I'm using MIDL to generate the DLLData.c file. The contents of the MIDL file are as follows:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[object,uuid(187c17c8-d5fb-4599-ac9d-75747fbdb964)]
interface IShape : IUnknown {
    HRESULT Draw();
};

[object,uuid(73f12c63-0466-4e09-aee0-8ffe6cc4dfcb)]
interface ICircle : IShape {
    HRESULT GetRadius([out] double* radius);
};

[object,uuid(4fae6fed-52ca-4069-8eaf-54f09b40f4a8)]
interface ISquare : IShape {
    HRESULT GetSideLength([out] double* sideLength);
};

[uuid(2f2b7408-b102-49ea-bdd3-81c9b74fca15)]
coclass CSquare {
    [default]  interface ISquare;
};

[uuid(87166cdd-6a6f-4276-979d-f99dfec7d97d)]
coclass CCircle {
    [default]  interface ICircle;
};

[uuid(1e899be1-dea5-4fcb-8dfc-2458a36e4052)]
coclass CShapeFactory {
    [default] interface IClassFactory;
};

HRESULT __stdcall CoShapeCreator(IID shapeInterface, PVOID* shape);
```

I've tried registering the DLL without implementing DllGetClassObject, but I encountered the `CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE ClassFactory cannot supply requested class` error, indicating that the ClassFactory cannot supply the requested class.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Remove dlldata.c from your server project.  It is meant to be used only by the proxy/stub  project, if you decide to create one.